# Android TextView settext() Nullpointer

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, textview

In my Android app, I'm trying to display a personalized message "Welcome, [name]!" when the app starts up. Through error logs I've determined that I successfully save a user's name after he/she is prompted to give it, and successfully retrieve that name on subsequent startups. But when I try to change the default "Welcome!" to "Welcome, [name]!" using settext, I get a null pointer exception.

My XML (activity_main.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFC2"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_textview"
    android:text="Welcome!"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:typeface="serif"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Java

```
public class main extends Activity {

TextView mainTextView;
private static final String PREFS = "prefs";
private static final String PREF_NAME = "name";
SharedPreferences mainSharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
    String name = mainSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_NAME, "");
    if(name.length() > 0){mainTextView.setText("Welcome, " + name + "!" );}
    else{greeting();}

    }
}
```

Based on other, similar posts, I've tried making sure I'm using setContentView on the xml file that contains the relevant TextView, and I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. It still gives me a NullPointerException. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If any of the answers bellow solves your problem, please mark it as the answer by clicking the checkmark icon next to the answer score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE is on the preceeding line. You haven't initialized your `mainSharedPreferences` object.

Comment: Beat me by however long it takes to press enter haha

Comment: That fixed it! Can't believe I was so off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

String name;

static String EXTRA_NAME;

EditName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

name = EditName.getText().toString();

Intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NAME", name);

you will have the EditName (what user inputs)in the string name and you can also put the string name    in a static string EXTRA NAME if you want to send that to another class...or you can create a separate class that can be used as object ..with getters and setters

or maybe you have to set text view in the xml file
android:text="name"